# A Better Way to Detect Touch vs Click Events

Tags: javascript, jquery

So, I've gone through many iterations of my code, but I think I've finally come up with the ultimate way to detect click vs tap events using a universal jQuery plugin. The plugin requires a hidden input field to store the "touchMove" flag. Does anyone know of a way (looking at my code) to store the flag in a global variable? I tried declaring a global `touchMove` variable, but unfortunately, javascript functions copy global variables to a local copy within the scope.

Anyway, here's what I got:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#touch-me").touch(function() {
    console.log("I have been activated!");
  });
});

$.fn.touch = function(callback) {
  var touch = false;
  $(this).on("click", function(e) {
    if (!touch) {
      console.log("I click!");
      let callbackReal = callback.bind(this);
      callbackReal(this, e);
    } else {
      touch = true;
    }
    touch = false;
  });
  $(this).on("touchend", function(e) {
    $(this).blur();
    if (typeof e.touches != typeof undefined) {
      e.preventDefault();
      touch = true;
      if ($("#touchMove").val() == 'moved') {
        console.log("You moved your finger, so I quit!");
        $("#touchMove").val('');
        return false;
      } else {
        console.log("I touch!");
        let callbackReal = callback.bind(this);
        callbackReal(this, e);
      }
    }
  });
  $(this).on("touchmove", function(e) {
    $("#touchMove").val('moved');
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="touch-me">Touch or Click on ME</button>
<input type="hidden" id="touchMove" value="" />
```

I also have my code on GitHub:
https://github.com/cloudmedia/jQuery.touch.js

And here is a fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/cloudulus/7n9deqxb/

Any suggestions to improve my code would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can set any global variable anytime using `window.touchMove=true` for example.

Comment: Indeed you could but it's kind of messy to declare separate variables globally. Since jQuery already is one itself, you could also do `$.touchMove` and avoid further cluttering of the window object.

Comment: Thanks, @Shikkediel. I didn't know you could access jQuery properties like that! How simple, yet incredibly useful. I can't believe I didn't know this. All the workarounds I've done in the past... I put your suggestion in my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the final code as edited by @Shikkediel:

```js
$.fn.touch = function(callback) {

  $.touch = {
    action: "",
    move: false,
    event: false
  }

  return this.on("click", function(e) {
      if (!$.touch.event) {
        $.touch.action = "click";
        let callbackReal = callback.bind(this);
        callbackReal(this, e);
      }
      $.touch.event = false;
    })
    .on("touchend", function(e) {
      $(this).blur();
      $.touch.event = true;
      if ($.touch.move) {
        $.touch.move = false;
        return;
      } else {
        $.touch.action = "touch";
        let callbackReal = callback.bind(this);
        callbackReal(this, e);
      }
    })
    .on("touchmove", function() {
      $.touch.move = true;
    });
}

$("#clickme").touch(function() {
  console.log("Action: " + $.touch.action);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="clickme">Click or Touch Me!</button>
```

Great job, Shikkediel. Thank you!